# Optimize Oracle 11g SQL*Plus connection for large remote SELECTs

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus, remote

Which options should I set in SQL*Plus for a script that runs multiple SELECTs, (some are JOINs) to SPOOL the results as text (CSV) in order to optimize these SELECTs, specifically one resulting in a 50 MB file, so that they take shorter to run, while the connection runs over the Internet? There's only read-only access, so I'm wondering what the options may be.

Comment: What problem are you getting? I've never had any problem just running the queries and spooling the output. 50Mb isn't so much data these days.

Comment: @Colin'tHart The script takes over half an hour to run, and the 50 MB SELECT takes most of that time. Thanks for contributing your experience.

Comment: Maybe you could store the query results in temporary tables and just spool those with `select *`? Materialized views could be a good solution for this -- simply refresh, and then run the script to spool.

Comment: What makes you think that SQL*Plus is the bottleneck that you can improve by setting its options?

Comment: OP said the connection is made through internet. When fetching large amount of data, the default value 15 of SQL*Plus `arraysize` parameter can be a serious bottleneck on a local network, but on high latency (internet compared to LAN is high latency) channels, it is even worse. With that setting the client fetches the results in 15 row chunks, doing network roundtrips on every 15 rows. `arraysize` can be set as high as `5000`.

Comment: @Colin'tHart temporary tables are out of the question - I only have read-only access - no CREATE.

Comment: @mustaccio I'm sure something is not going on normally, since a single SELECT takes about half an hour to run. If the bottleneck is somewhere else, there was nothing I could think of that I could change, but I would consider other options, yes. I'm testing Balazs Papp's suggestion right now and hope it will make a difference.

Comment: I've finally added `SET FLUSH OFF` (but before I had `SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET ROWPREFETCH 5000;
SET LOBPREFETCH 16384;
SET ARRAYSIZE 5000;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000` and now it's running two large SELECTs (50 MB resulting CSV each) and many other smaller ones in less than 10 minutes (7 minutes I think). Thank you @BalazsPapp for pointing me in the right direction. Note: I'm using Oracle SQL CL (console executable) and I'm not sure these changes were responsible, maybe something just changed (such as the server being less used at this hour).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the 11g client, you should use at least 12.2, because:

1. 11g is outdated
2. 12.2 has builtin support for generating CSV output ([MARKUP)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/starting-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B3B93959-2119-447D-A9D3-2349DDD70435), `sqlplus -M "CSV ON" user/password@address`
3. you can simply start 12.2 with the `-fast` option ([-F[ast]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/starting-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-EF787590-D6D2-46A1-B481-E5CBAD9F48AC)), that sets (which you can set and tune further manually as well):

> ```
> ARRAYSIZE = 100
> LOBPREFETCH = 16384
> PAGESIZE = 50000
> ROWPREFETCH = 2
> STATEMENTCACHE = 20
> ```

Comment: No, 11g is the Oracle server I'm connecting to. I see I did get the 11.2 SQL Plus, for compatibility concerns, probably. I'll check if I can use a newer one. Thank you so much!

Comment: @bitoolean 12c client is compatible with 11g databases, go for it.

Comment: @bitoolean 12.2 client can be used with 11.2.0.4 or 11.2.3 databases according to note [207303.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1). Client 12.1 2ith lower 11g version, too.

Comment: I've tried this with SQL*Plus 12.2 and even 18.3, and even SQLCl... I even tried a combination of ArraySize 5000 and ROWPREFETCH 5000. After 10 minutes, it's still not done running. Thanks for the pointers nonetheless - I realize this should have helped. I guess the problem must be with the server. This seems to have helped others. Or maybe this is normal with Oracle software.